# CSV reading with pandas doesn't return expected value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to search for a specific keyword in a specific CSV column and print the value found, although when I get the print it returns the whole row.

I have tried the `data.filter` function command I didn't have much luck.

What I plan to do is:

1. Get to the right column
2. Search for a value in the specific column
3. Print a value from another named column but not the whole row.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

#list only specific columns
list_columns = ["Name", "Size","Colour"]

#read csv in the defined columns above
data = pd.read_csv("Database.csv", usecols=list_columns)

##print a specific column only
#print(data["Colour"]) 

#define keyword,and wherre/what to look for
keyword = data[data["Name"] == 'Jeans']

#print the value found
print (keyword.head())
```

And the output:

```
    Name Colour     Size
0  Jeans  Black  X-Large
```

I feel like I need to tell it to print only a value from a specific column instead of `keyword.head()` - is that correct?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Thanks, @JeffUK for the kind reply. For example, let say I look in the column Name for a specific value Jeans, I want the code to output the value from a specific column let's assume Size. I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: better show in question (not in comment) example data and expected result (both as table/DataFrame)

Comment: if you want only value from one column then use `keyword[column_name].head()` or `keyword.head()[column_name]`

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't try to use `keyword["Size"]`

Comment: @furas Thanks mate, I have tried it but the problem is that it returns `0    X-Large
Name: Size, dtype: object` I only want it to return the value of that cell in this case just the word X-Large, any idea on how I could isolate just the word?

Comment: I actually worked it out! I just used print `(*keyword["Size"], sep='\n')` and it removed the index! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

Use

```
print(*keyword["Size"], sep='\n')
```

---

If you want to store the results in a variable you can use

```
lst = [*keyword["Size"]]
```

or even better,

```
lst = keyword['Size'].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks, @richardec, I did that as I mentioned before and it worked well to print the value although I now want to store the value into a variable and I can't use that. Got an idea of what I could use?

Comment: @Matteo check the answer now. :)

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much! It works like a charm :) And so simple too, been scratching my head all day! @richardec